# ActiveDirectory Samba4 SMBHome authentication error

Tags: active-directory, mac-osx, samba, network-share, samba4

I have a samba4 server up and running providing an
ADC. One OS X machine joined this AD and is configured to
use the UNC path for the home directory, but the login failed
because automountd fails to mount the SMBHome (native homeDirectory) with an authentication error. Using a local home works,
how can I debug the automountd process with a user currently not logged in? (with a local user)

I'd like to have the SMBHome provided directory mounted and used as the home directory of the user in OS X.

My **smb.conf**:

```
# Global parameters
[global]
        workgroup = INTRANET
        realm = INTRANET.APPBASE.HAMBURG
        netbios name = SERVER
        server role = active directory domain controller
        server services = s3fs, rpc, nbt, wrepl, ldap, cldap, kdc, drepl, winbindd, ntp_signd, kcc, dnsupdate
        idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes

[netlogon]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/intranet.appbase.hamburg/scripts
        read only = No

[sysvol]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
        read only = No

[Users]
        read only = no
        writeable = yes
        path = /Users
        browseable = no
        create mode = 0600
        directory mode = 0700
```

SMBHome is in format

```
\\server.domain\Users\testuser
```

ls -l /

```
...
drwxrws---   3 root users  4096 Jan 23 15:06 Users
...
```

ls -l /Users

```
drwx--S---+ 2 3000009 users 4096 Jan 23 15:06 testuser
```

I'm thankful for any advice as there is no "Howto create an AD with samba4 and make your OS X client use it for login and network home" :-/